# Universal generalization and the Deduction theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

### Universal generalization

The rule of universal generalization in FOL is stated as follows:

> (Gen) From $p$ we may infer $(\forall x)p$ provided $x$ does not occur free in any premiss which has been used in the proof of $p$.

I don't understand what this means, particularly for deduction sequences. Given a set of formulae $S$ and a formula $p$ which has $x$ as a free variable, I can interpret the above in several ways. Suppose $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ is a deduction sequence of $S$ and $p_i = p$ for some $i$; then:

> (Gen1) If $x$ does not occur free in $S$, then $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n, (\forall x)p)$ is also a deduction sequence
>
> (Gen2) If $x$ does not occur free in $p_j$ for all $j<i$, then $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n, (\forall x)p)$ is also a deduction sequence.
>
> (Gen2') If there is a deduction sequence $(p_1',\ldots,p_m' = p)$ that does not contain free occurrences of $x$, then $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n, (\forall x)p)$ is also a deduction sequence.

[Say a deduction sequence $(p_1,\ldots, p_n)$ is $x$-independent if $x$ does not occur free in $\{p_j \mid p_j \in S\}$.]

> (Gen3) If $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{i-1})$ is $x$-independent then $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n, (\forall x)p)$ is also a deduction sequence.
>
> (Gen 3') If there is an $x$-independent deduction sequence $(p_1',\ldots,p_m' = p)$, then $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n, (\forall x)p)$ is also a deduction sequence.
>
> $\vdots$

I'm looking the most inclusive definition that results in a sound logical system. It must be easy to work with.

### Example: the Deduction Theorem

For example, in the proof of the Deduction Theorem we start with a set of formulae $S$ and formulae $p,q$ so that $S\vdash (p\Rightarrow q)$; we seek to prove that $S\cup\{p\}\vdash q$. I would like to proceed as follows:

> Write a deduction of $(p\Rightarrow q)$ from $S$, append $p$ and apply modus ponens to get a deduction of $q$ from $S\cup\{p\}$.

This doesn't quite work if (Gen1), say with a variable $x$, has been used in the deduction of $(p\Rightarrow q)$ and $x$ appears free in $p$, since then (Gen1) with variable $x$ is invalidated in $S\cup\{p\}$. So it appears (Gen1) is an inadequate definition (and I don't want to have to change the statement of the deduction theorem, as in [here](https://planetmath.org/deductiontheoremholdsforfirstorderlogic))

> Qs: Which (Gen $k$) is correct, if any? Are some of them equivalent? What's the best/standard way(s) to define (Gen)?

Comment: On a side note, the deduction theorem is the converse of the result you are proving in the last part.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Sorry, I had it on my notes as $S \vdash (p\Rightarrow q)$ iff $S\cup\{p\} \vdash q$.

Comment: The restriction is needed in order to prevent the invalid $\vdash Px \to \forall x Px$.

Comment: In a nutshell, from $\vdash  Px$, then $\vdash \forall x Px$ is fine, while $Px \vdash \forall x Px$ is not.